# how to load active/nonactive buttons

Tags: actionscript-3

Im creating a column of 5 elements. When you click once the element from column you cant click it again even if you close the fla and load it again.And you can click the elements below only if the elements over(the current element you want to click) has been clicked.

So Ive asked a question like this before and ppl told me to separate/make the logic into 2 functions - one that if its the 1st load of the FLA you create the column ( **createColumn()** ), and 1 that if its 2nd 3rd etc load of the FLA you load the column  ( **loadColumn()** ).
So i did that but now I have a problem solving the logic for the loading **loadColumn()**. What I don`t know is :

how do i only make the element straight below the last clicked element, to be active and the rest of them to be inactive until this element is clicked.Something like this

1st load of fla ->I create the column and click the 1st and2nd elements,then i close the fla.

2nd load of fla->I see that elements 1 and 2 are nonClickable (lets say that i had buyed them the 1st time), element 3 is clickable and element 4 will be clickable if i click (buy) element 3. So I click only element 3 and close again the fla.

3rd load of fla->Now I see that element 1,2 and 3 nonClickable and only element 4 can be clicked.So i click it and then 5 gets active to so i click it too.

last load of fla-> now i see that all of the elements are nonClickable.
[image]

So far I have only the logic that fades out the buttons that have been clicked before, but i dont have the logic to make the next button be clickable.

I have 2 classes: Main()

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var savedData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Line_37");
    private var buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr:Array = [];

    private var myButtons_Arr:Array = [];
    private var row:int = 5;

    public function Main()
    {
        if (savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr == undefined)
        {
            createColumn();
        }
        if (savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr != undefined)
        {
            loadColumn();
        }

    }

    private function createColumn():void
    {
        trace("                               1st time loading this game\n");
        var lastRowElement:BitmapButton = null;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(60,60,false,Math.floor((0xff + Math.random() * 0xffffff)));
            var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpd);
            var myImage_mc:BitmapButton = new BitmapButton  ;
            myImage_mc.addChild(myImage);

            myImage_mc.x = 250;
            myImage_mc.y = 0 + i *( myImage_mc.height + 10);
            myImage_mc.name = "myImage_mc" + i;
            this.addChild(myImage_mc);

            myImage_mc.mouseChildren = false;
            myImage_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
            myImage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

            if ((lastRowElement == null))
            {
                myImage_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                myImage_mc.buttonMode = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lastRowElement.next_1 = myImage_mc;
            }
            lastRowElement = myImage_mc;
        }
    }

    private function loadColumn():void
    {
        trace("                               Game was played before\n");

        buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr = savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr;
        trace("names of clicked buttons: " + buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr + "\n");
        var number_ofSavedObjects:int = savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr.length;

        //-----
        for (var i:int = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(60,60,false,Math.floor((0xff + Math.random() * 0xffffff)));
            var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpd);
            var myImage_mc:BitmapButton = new BitmapButton  ;
            myImage_mc.addChild(myImage);

            myImage_mc.x = 250;
            myImage_mc.y = 0 + i * (myImage_mc.height + 10);
            myImage_mc.name = "myImage_mc" + i;
            this.addChild(myImage_mc);

            myImage_mc.mouseChildren = false;
            myImage_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
            myImage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

            for (var h:int = 0; h < number_ofSavedObjects; h++)
            {
                var nameOf_lastSavedObject:String = savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr[h];

                if (myImage_mc.name == nameOf_lastSavedObject)
                {
                    trace("match: button " + myImage_mc.name + " will have 0.1 alpha");
                    myImage_mc.alpha = 0.1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var nameOfCell:String = ev.target.name;

        if (ev.target is BitmapButton)
        {
            var btn:BitmapButton = ev.currentTarget as BitmapButton;
            ev.currentTarget.alpha = 0.1;

            if (btn.next_1 != null)
            {
                btn.next_1.mouseEnabled = true;
                btn.next_1.buttonMode = true;
            }
            btn.buttonMode = false;
            btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

            buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr.push(nameOfCell);
            savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr = buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr;
            savedData.flush();
            savedData.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and **BitmapButton()**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class BitmapButton extends Sprite
{
    public var next_1:BitmapButton = null;
}
```

I just want to say also that I did try to solve it myself.I did try with a boolean that changes when the active cells has  the name of the button is the nextCell name.
Something like if cell.name == nextToClickCell.name.Also tried making  Arrays where i put all the untouched another and all the touched elements.Also tried saving another data to the sharedObject and using that data to compare what element will be active now.Yet ... i cant do it
PS: the "Line_37" for the name of the sharedObj is times i tried on this file,sadly to say this is my 3rd different file name with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loading previous Data

Here's your revised `loadColumn()`

```
private function loadColumn():void {
    createColumn();
    trace("                               Game was played before\n");

    buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr = savedData.data.myClickedButtons_Arr;
    trace("names of clicked buttons:" + buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr + "\n");

    var btn;
    for each (var btnName:String in buttonThatHaveBeenClicked_Arr) {
        trace("Disabling " + btnName);
        btn = this.getChildByName(btnName);
        btn.mouseChildren = false;
        btn.mouseEnabled = false;
        btn.alpha = 0.1;
    }

    var btnIndex:int = btnName.split("myImage_mc")[1]
    if (btnIndex + 1 < row) {
        btn = this.getChildByName("myImage_mc" + (btnIndex + 1));
        btn.mouseChildren = true;
        btn.mouseEnabled = true;
        btn.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm with me this isnt working. it is the same staff -> i still cant click anything after i load the fla again.Im adding this code Just before closing the **onClick()** function right? Can you pls upload the files somewhere?

Comment: hmmmm Ok i might be wrong but your code doesnt change things after loading the fla for 2nd,3rd etc. time. It only makes so that i get an the button below active and the upper button - inactive.What im trying is to save those states and send them to the next load of the fla, but i dont know why.Hope you can understand me

Comment: I've updated the the answer to explicitly demonstrate the change I'm suggesting.  That solution (so far) only addresses making sure that the current button clicked is disabled and that the next button (in the column) be enabled.  If your concern is that your buttons aren't updating immediately after opening your document (on the 2nd and subsequent loads), then the issue is with your `init()` function starting at `else if (savedData.data.myArray != undefined) {`.  Let me know.

Comment: Well yes :D that is what I aim for -> `updating immediately after opening your document (on the 2nd and subsequent loads)`. I know that its in the `else if (savedData.data.myArray != undefined) {` like you pointed out, but i cant figure out how to solve it. :) can you help ?

Comment: I'm in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29004/adobe-scripting-languages (for now), but I've updated the solution.  I believe that should do it.